# Display number of characters in WordPress comments

Tags: jquery, wordpress, comments

i used this php code for limit Wordpress comments length in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpb_preprocess_comment' );

function wpb_preprocess_comment($comment) {
    if ( strlen( $comment['comment_content'] ) > 1400 ) {
        wp_die('Comment is too long. Please keep your comment under 1400 characters.');
    }
```

How to display number of available characters left to be updated as the user types? It should be some simple text as "1400 characters left" in the corner of field.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#area").on("keydown", function() {
      let count = $(this).val().length;
      $("#count").html(1400 - count - 1 + " characters left.");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<div id="count">
</div>
```

Comment: I mean there is too JS solution: https://wpengineer.com/2321/comment-length-limiter/ But how to connect it with WordPress comments? Where paste or call this code?

Comment: @klvb Aren't you able to add scripts to your WordPress site? It shouldn't be much of a problem following the steps mentioned e.g. here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/

Comment: I understand how to use hooks. But what use in add_action? function wpb_hook_javascript_footer() {
    ?>
        <script>
          // your javscript code goes
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('???', 'wpb_hook_javascript_footer');

Comment: @klvb I think it's 'wp_footer' according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer.

Comment: Sorry, im lost. I used in functions.php this code and nothing changed: function wpb_count() {
    ?>
        <script>
         $("#area").on("keydown", function() {
  let count = $(this).val().length;
  $("#count").html(1400 - count - 1 + " characters left.");
});
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_count');

Comment: @klvb And you have a textarea with the id "area" and a div with the id "count" in your page? And do you already include jQuery? Also you should wrap this script in a $(document).ready(); function (I adjusted this in my answer so you can copy it from there).

Comment: I have this html textarea: <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required="required"></textarea>. It is default WordPress comment field, i probably cant modfiy that.

Comment: @klvb You can just change $("#area").on("keydown"...) to $("texarea[name='comment']").on("keydown"...) but it would be necessary to add the element with the id "count" to the page so the "... characters left" text can be shown.

Comment: @klvb Sorry no, I don't know how to add an ID element to WP comments.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
function wpb_countx() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    ?>
        <script>
   jQuery(function($) {
    // configure
    var comment_input = $( '#commentform textarea' );
    var submit_button = $( '#commentform .form-submit' );
    var comment_limit_chars = 1400;
    // stop editing here

    // display how many characters are left
    $( '<div class="comment_limit_info"><span>' + comment_limit_chars + '</span> zbývá znaků</div>' ).insertAfter( comment_input );

    comment_input.bind( 'keyup', function() {
        // calculate characters left
        var comment_length = $(this).val().length;
        var chars_left = comment_limit_chars - comment_length;

        // display characters left
        $( '.comment_limit_info span' ).html( chars_left );

        // hide submit button if too many chars were used
        if (submit_button)
            ( chars_left < 0 ) ? submit_button.hide() : submit_button.show();
    });
}); 
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_countx');
```